# Change content on the fly

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am currently working in dynamic template creation where user ***can drag any defined element from source area into destination area.***  Now after dropping user can modify it's text (change / add new).

I have done dragging and dropping but how to change it's text after dropping. ?

[image]

Is there any javascript library available to help me out?

Comment: You're not really explaining how you want to edit. In place? In a TextArea? A modal with an editor? How? There is a simple option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content which is almost as widely supported as drap and drop: https://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken look at the [HTML contenteditable Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)?

```html
<div contenteditable="true">This div is editable. Try to change this text.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple. After dropping your element, change it's content to textarea which can be styled to look same as before dragged.

For question about library. I would use jQuery because of it's easy content manipulation. You do something like this:

```
function eventAfterDrop(container) {
  container.html('<textarea name="textarea" class="same-as-dragged"></textarea>');
}
```

This will do only one thing and that's change of content to textarea. It can be done many different ways. I'm just trying to show you which way to go.

PS: If you show some code, someone can help you to do this exactly for your code.